# Distinguish OOTO and blacklist bounces on AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, blacklist, email-bounces

With SES, when you send an email to someone who has an OOTO (out of the office) message, SES returns a bounce notification that has something like this:

```
'bounce': {
  'bounceType': 'Transient', 
  'bounceSubType': 'General', 
  'bouncedRecipients': [{'emailAddress': 'ooto@example.com'}]
  'feedbackId': '...', 
  'timestamp': '...'
}
```

When you send an email to someone and the SES sender is on an IP blacklist, then the recipient email server might reject the message.  When this happens, you get a bounce notification that looks like this:

```
'bounce': {
  'bounceType': 'Transient'
  'bounceSubType': 'General',
  'bouncedRecipients': [
    {'action': 'failed', 
     'status': '5.7.1',
     'diagnosticCode': '... blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net ...',
     'emailAddress': 'blacklist@example.com'}
    ],  
  'reportingMTA': 'dsn;a8-41.smtp-out.amazonses.com',
  'remoteMtaIp': '...',
  'feedbackId': '...', 
  'timestamp': '...'
}
```

There are clearly differences between the two, but it is hard to know which differences can be used to reliably distinguish between an OOTO and a blacklist rejection.  Who knows what other OOTO or blacklist notifications will look like...

Any idea what to use?  Absent better ideas, I think I'll look for action:failed in the recipient list.

Comment: I would be extremely cautious with trying to manage something like this.  OOTO is not an RFC standard and so every system is going to implement it their own way.  You'll get it working with a Microsoft solution and then you need to deal with Google.  Then outlook.com which will do it differently than the enterprise Microsoft stuff and so on.

Comment: @stdunbar, I just want to ignore OOTO but I'd like to identify the blacklist rejections so I can do something about them.

Comment: I'm surprised that the `bounceType` in a blacklist bounce is `Transient`.  I would have expect a hard fail on that (a 500 series response in SMTP).  But it looks like you're correct to look for the `failed` in the recipients section.  I agree with your backup plan.